# Entity Framework, Linq : concatenating results from child table

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have an existing linq query which gets some data into a view model object. This is working fine.

I want to add a new property for data from child table which will have column values from a child table in a comma separated string format.
Problem: I am not able to concatenate the results using string.join

Simplified version of tables showing only relevant fields

part

| id | part number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC1 |
| 2 | DEF1 |

vendor

| id | vendorname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | acme |
| 2 | john |

vendor part name (vendor specific part number)

| partid | vendorid | partname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | GDSE-553-32 |
| 1 | 2 | JWWVV-HH-01 |

simplified version of query

```
result = (from p in DBContext.Parts.Where(w => w.EquipmentId == eId)
    select new PartModel
        {
            Id = p.Id,
        Number = p.PartNumber,
        VendorPartNames= String.Join(",", DBContext.VendorPartName.Where(w => w.PartId == p.Id).Select(s => s.PartName))//this line causes exception (shown below)
});
```

Exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.String[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Please note: the actual query has some joins and other columns, so please dont suggest solutions that requires joins.

If I change the "VendorPartName" to a List type , I can get the results without any problems.

My only problem is in "**How to convert the results for "VendorPartName" property to a comma separated strings?**"
eg: based on sample table data provided, it should be
*GDSE-553-32, JWWVV-HH-01*

Comment: So, you have to do postprocessing, EF do not support `string.Join` SQL translation .

Comment: EF not support `string.Join` you need execute the query without concatenation, then you can use linq for create your object using `string.join`

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework does not support `String.Join()` method.

So, what we can do is to fetch `VendorPartNames` as a string collection and then we can later separate it with `,`.

**Note:** For this, we would first use an anonymous object and later convert it to `PartModel`.

So your query would look like this:

```
var parts = DBContext.Parts
               .Where(w => w.EquipmentId == eId)
               .Select(p => new {
                    Id = p.Id,
                    Number = p.PartNumber,
                    VendorPartNames = p.VendorPartName.Select(n => n.PartName)
               }).ToList();

var result = parts.Select(i => new PartModel {
               Id = i.Id,
               Number = i.Number,
               VendorPartNames = String.Join(",", i.VendorPartNames)
             }).ToList();
```